# Difference between two flux

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have two fluxes where order is not important and I want to get one resultant flux with the difference. How can I do this?

Example:

```java
Flux<Tweet> remoteTweets = Flux.just(
        new Tweet("tag1",new TweetID("text","name"),"userimage","country","place"),
        new Tweet("tag2",new TweetID("text","name"),"userimage","country","place")
);

Flux<Tweet> localTweets = Flux.just(
        new Tweet("tag1",new TweetID("text","name"),"userimage","country","place")
);
```

Result expected: `tag2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `localTweets` is a finite stream and fits into memory, then the following works:

```java
Flux<Tweet> remoteTweets = Flux.just(
        new Tweet("tag1", new TweetID("text", "name"), "userimage", "country", "place"),
        new Tweet("tag2", new TweetID("text", "name"), "userimage", "country", "place")
);

Flux<Tweet> localTweets = Flux.just(
        new Tweet("tag1", new TweetID("text", "name"), "userimage", "country", "place")
).cache(); // note cache operator here, to avoid mutiple subscription

remoteTweets
        .filterWhen(remoteTweet -> localTweets.hasElement(remoteTweet).map(hasElement -> !hasElement))
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

If the stream is finite, but not fits into memory, then you should leave the `cache` operator out. That will mean `localTweets` Flux will be subscribed to multiple times.

If the stream is infinite, you should apply some windowing strategy (e.g. check tweets only from last 10 minutes).